# ASP.NET Custom Control Property Grayed

Tags: asp.net

I've a custom control derived from BaseControl.

When I look at the property of this control, the poperty is grayed out i.e. unable to key in the values.

Could anyone please suggest why it's not working?

Comment: Code sample? Can you get the intellisense when accessing the property programmatically?

Comment: Which properties are greyed out? Also, if you're creating a control for the web, you should inherit from WebControl, and if it's not going to display anything you should inherit from Control. A walk-through for this is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhzc935f.aspx).

Comment: Is it a user control or a server control?

Comment: @jhsowter, it is a server control

Comment: You should be inheriting WebControl.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer inherit from Control, but you have to add the INamingContainer interface.
The Class BaseControl from which you derive your one, wich kind of object is it?